# is resize first faster than convert first in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to convert and resizing image but I'm not sure which best order.
That image is just screenshots dan grabbed every time (screen recording).

Yes I know no matter which order eventually it will gave same output, but I care about performance.
Since I don't need alpha color so I remove it with convert function.
I was trying benchmark but I'm not sure if my test is valid about image processing that I do.

Suppose `currentFrame` is numpy array of current screenshot

First case: resize first then convert

```
while True:
  currentFrame = np.asarray(sct.grab(sct.monitors[1]))
  t0 = time()
  currentFrame = cv.resize(currentFrame, resolution)
  currentFrame = cv.cvtColor(currentFrame, cv.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
  print(time() - t0)
```

it gave me average output `0.0019386794215949`

And for second case

Second case: convert first then resize

```
while True:
  currentFrame = np.asarray(sct.grab(sct.monitors[1]))
  t0 = time()
  currentFrame = cv.cvtColor(currentFrame, cv.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
  currentFrame = cv.resize(currentFrame, resolution)
  print(time() - t0)
```

it gave me average output `0.0028475606945199`

Comment: I don't think a single shot `time()` is a very good way of testing - have a look at `timeit` in IPython.

Comment: I think the answer depends if you are resizing to larger image or to smaller image, but that information is missing from your question. In case you are scaling up, apply color conversion first, in case you are scaling down apply color conversion last.

Comment: Okay I forgot mention about resize. The resize is scaling down means the image will became smaller.